# How do I shield my Windows contacs from 3rd party software?

Tags: windows-7, contacts, privacy-protection

On Windows 7 I am using the onboard *Windows contacts* solution for all my contacts that contain a lot of personal information which I dont want to spread.

**Are those contacts read-protected against other programs I might install? If not, how would I protect that valuable information other than blocking all programs with a firewall?**

On mobile systems, the contacts permission is always a big deal but is never mentioned for desktops, which is kind if strange.

Comment: Are you using the 'Windows Contacts'? Where the contacts are just xml files that can be opened and viewed?

Comment: Yes I am using *Windows contacs* but I dont know if they are saved as xml's. Not at the desk right now.

Comment: Simple - don't install untrustworthy software.

Comment: That is not solution. Tell me which software you trust, and proof you can.

Comment: On Windows any program you run has access to all your files. This is by design.

Comment: I was pretty sure it is like that. That is why I am asking about a solution. I.e: Use a 3rd party contacts software or I don't know encrypt just the contacts folder...

Comment: All the comments are correct, but I wonder why there is no possibility to encrypt this valuable data so that trojans or other malware cannot easily access it.